# Resizing child widget by resizing dialog box with mouse

Tags: python, pygtk

I am using pygtk to create a dialog box with the following code:

```
def __init__(self):    
    gtk.Dialog.__init__(self,
        title="Add new block",
        buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_REJECT, gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK),
    )


self.set_size_request(600, 300)
vbox = gtk.VBox()
self.vbox.pack_start(vbox, True, True, 0)
self.block_hbox = gtk.HBox(gtk.FALSE,0)
vbox.pack_start(self.block_hbox,False,False,7)
self.block_hbox.show()


self.block = gtk.Label("Enter block name")
self.block_hbox.pack_start(self.block,False,False,7)    
self.block.show()
self.block_e = gtk.Entry()
self.block_e.set_size_request(310,-1)
self.block_hbox.pack_end(self.block_e,False)
self.block_e.show()
```

When I try to increase the size of dialog box by using mouse cursor, size of child widget (`gtk.Entry`) does not change. I want it to increase its size by increasing the dialog box's size. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just got my mistake. I should have used:

```
self.block_hbox.pack_end(self.block_e,True)
```